# VirtualBox にて AlmaLinux が "Install AlmaLinux" を選択後、黒い画面で止まってしまう

Tags: linux, virtualbox

VMでAlmaLinuxを起動後、"Install AlmaLinux 8.5" を選択すると、添付画像の状態で停止してしまいます。

## 環境

### 本体環境

Windows 10 Pro
プロセッサ: i7-2600 3.4GHz
メモリ: 8GB
Oracle VirtualBox 6.1

### 仮想マシン環境

#### 一般

オレペーティングシステム: AlmaLinux-8.5

#### システム

メインメモリ: 2048MB
プロセッサ: 2

#### ディスプレイ

ビデオメモリ: 16MB
グラフィックコントローラ: VMSVGA

#### ストレージ

コントローラ:IDE
IDE セカンダリマスタ: [工学ドライブ]ubuntu-ja-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso(2.61GB)

## 試したこと

添付画像上部の `kernel bug at arch /x86/kernel/traps c654` について検索。（全くヒットしなかった）

---

添付画像
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 0):

私も一昨日まで使えていたのに、昨日から急に上記と同じと思われる事象に悩まされていました。いろいろ試行錯誤してみましたが、以下からV6.1.36をダウンロードすると解消しました。こちらの環境は以下の通りです。

ダウンロードサイト
https://www.oracle.com/jp/virtualization/technologies/vm/downloads/virtualbox-downloads.html

Windows 10 Pro
Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600K CPU @ 3.40GHz   3.40 GHz（未だ現役で使ってます）
v6.1.18 （事象発生バージョン）